# How to list all available themes in Magento?

Tags: magento, admin, skin

Is there a function in Magento to list all available skins?

I know I could use the quick and dirty method of getting a directory list of the skin/ directory but wanted to know the correct method as I am developing a module that I want to be transportable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of all available packages, use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getPackageList();
```

To get a list of all available themes, use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getThemeList();
```